# MVC5 - Culture Dependant ViewModel Validation

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller, internationalization, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a System that takes a phone-number and finds a user.

In my ViewModel i have

```
[MinLength(8)]
public string UserId {get;set;}
```

and in my View i use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserID)
```

This works fine.

Then it turns out that some countries use 8 digits and others use 9 or more digits in their phonenumbers.
I would like to keep the precise validation.
Is there any way i can make [MinLength(8)] Culture dependent?

Followup question would be, in some countries we can't use Phone-number, but instead a Social ID. Perhaps it now allows letters. Can i make Culture Dependent Regular Expressions as well?

Comment: Short answer is no. You could however write your own conditional validation attributes (for example a `[RequiredIf]` attribute performs validation based on the value of another property. In your case you would need a property to identify the culture. Start by looking at [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1) to get you started

Comment: That link provided a lot of very useful information. Thank you very much.
I think my needs can be meet, with the [Remote] attribute and a ServerSide Action.

Comment: The `[Remote]` attribute can be useful, but may not be the best option - you could be making a huge number of calls to the server. And `[Remote]` is client side only. You then have to repeat the validation again in the controller.